# How can I report spam based only on a Gmail return address?

Tags: gmail, spam-prevention

We just bumped into some spam on security SE. We mod nuked it, but I wanted to report the email address there. I found [this](https://support.google.com/mail/contact/abuse), but it seems the person needs to have mailed you spam:

> I would like to report a Gmail user **who has sent messages** that violate the Gmail Program Policies and/or Terms of Use.

In this case, no one received email from nor mailed the spammer.

Is there any link to report such an account?

> [image]

Comment: What kind of spam are you talking about?

Comment: @Rubén It's advertising some hacking of ATMs

Comment: Where is that advertising being posted?

Comment: @Rubén [Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/105454) (Answer already mod nuked, 10k only)

Comment: Maybe you can send them an email from a disposable account to have it as evidence.

Comment: @mgarciaisaia good idea!

Comment: Be careful when doing criminal investigation by your own. You could put yourself in risk and could be indicted for doing criminal activity. Before proceeding, ask for advice to a lawyer.

Answer (score 8):

This may not be specifically for email abuse, but if they have a Google+ profile associated with that email address you can report them.

On any user's Google+ profile page, just under their photograph on the left hand side, there is a drop-down for "More actions".  one of those is "Report this user".

I've never reported anyone, so I don't know what sort of response you would get.

Answer (score 5):

You can't.

Email addresses are easily, and regularly, spoofed. Heck, I've received spam that seemed to come from myself.

Google uses heuristics on the content *and* the headers to determine if something is spam. Even though you have some content, it's likely not enough to get a good score.

So, good on you for wanting to help get rid of this junk, but unless you got it in Gmail you can't report it to Google.

I hope you *did* use the spam flag on that post so Stack Exchange can get smarter about stopping spam.

Answer (score 5):

## Short answer

Carefully consider to file a report with the **Internet Crime Complaint Center** ([www.ic3.gov](http://www.ic3.gov)), a partnership between the **Federal Bureau of Investigation** and the **National White Collar Crime Center**.

## Long answer

The following quote, from https://support.google.com/mail/answer/190735?hl=en, is regarding impersonation, but this also could apply to other suspicious activities that could lead to commit [cybercrimes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cybercrime)

> Impersonation
>
> If you believe someone has created a Gmail address in an attempt to
>   impersonate your identity, you may wish to file a report with the
>   Internet Crime Complaint Center (www.ic3.gov), a partnership between
>   the Federal Bureau of Investigation and the National White Collar
>   Crime Center.
>
> In addition, we recommend contacting your state's Office of Consumer
>   Protection.
>
> Gmail is unable to participate in mediations involving third parties
>   regarding impersonation. To read the Gmail Terms of Use, please visit:
>   https://www.gmail.com/intl/en/mail/help/terms.html.

From [www.ic3.gov](http://www.ic3.gov)

> Filing a Complaint with the IC3
>
> The IC3 accepts online Internet crime complaints from either the
>   actual victim or from a third party to the complainant. We can best
>   process your complaint if we receive accurate and complete information
>   from you. Therefore, we request that you provide the following
>   information when filing a complaint:
>
> - Your name
> - Your mailing address
> - Your telephone number
>
> The name, address, telephone number, and Web address, if available, of
>   the individual or organization you believe defrauded you. Specific
>   details on how, why, and when you believe you were defrauded. Any
>   other relevant information you believe is necessary to support your
>   complaint.